# Chomp changes my string to 1

Tags: perl, chomp

In my code I assign a variable disc to equal the result of an command `disc` on my linux system. This outputs the string RESEARCH

```
my $disc = `disc`;
print "$disc\n";
$disc = chomp($disc);
print "$disc\n";
```

However when I use chomp to strip the newline character from the string it changes the string to 1. Here is the output

```
RESEARCH

1
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [perldoc -f chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
chomp VARIABLE
chomp( LIST )
chomp   This safer version of "chop" removes any trailing string that
        corresponds to the current value of $/ (also known as
        $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR in the "English" module). It returns the
        total number of characters removed from all its arguments.
```

The proper usage is to simply provide a variable or list that will be altered in place. The return value, which is what you use, is how many times it "chomped" its argument list. E.g.

```
chomp $disc;
```

Or even:

```
chomp(my $disc = `disc`);
```

For example, you may chomp an entire array or list, e.g.:

```
my @file = <$fh>;          # read a whole file
my $count = chomp(@file);  # counts how many lines were chomped
```

Of course, with a single scalar argument, the chomp return value can be only 1 or 0.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid assigning the chomp result to your variable:

```
$disc = chomp($disc);
```

use:

```
chomp($disc);
```

This is because chomp modifies the given string and returns the total number of characters removed from all its argument

Answer (score 2):

Just use `chomp $disc` without any affectation beacause [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the number of chars removed.

Comment: `chomp $disc` also returns 1

Comment: @moadeep: Yes of course, it returns the number of char removed. just use `chomp $disc;`